# Android Device Manager not showing the device manager

Tags: android, android-emulator, installation

I downloaded the latest android sdk from Google and unzipped it in my home folder in my Linux machine. Then I added the path of the tools and platform tools directories to my system path. Next I updated the sdk (all from command line). After this, I was trying to create a a virtual device, hence I ran the android command from command line. However, although it was expected show the options for creating devices, it does not show any. Moreover, it shows only the SDK and API versions. Its title bar also reads Android SDK Manager, instead of Android SDK and Device Manager. So please help me creating a device. Although I am able to use the command line to create the device, I am unable to do it from the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Android SDK and AVD Manager" was split into two separate windows a couple of months ago. Unfortunately, the Android Web site is still out of date with respect to instructions.

Running `android` brings up the SDK Manager. You can get to the AVD Manager from the Tools | Manage AVDs... menu choice.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not realize the menu bar options due to the stupid Unity interface on Ubuntu. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an Android virtual device on command line. All you must do is reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html) tutorial.

Basically you generate a list of system image targets with this command:

```
android list targets
```

And then you create virtual device:

```
android create avd -n <name> -t <targetID> [-<option> <value>] ...
```

Here is an example:

```
android create avd -n my_android1.5 -t 2
```

This command creates a virtual device with "my_android1.5" as name and '2' id as system image. For further information please visit the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html).